# Unexpected result in pointer arithmetic, in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C and I'm trying to solve one of the exercise problem of K&R book. The problem is to detect the whether a given string ends with the same content of other string.

For example, if string one is `ratandcat` and string two is `cat`. Then it is true that string two ends in string one. To solve this, I came up with half a solution and I got struck with pointers.

My idea is to find the position where string one ends and also the position the string two starts, so that I can proceed further. I have this code:

```
int strEnd(char *s,char *t){
    int ans,slength =0 ,tlength = 0;
    while(*s++)
        slength++;
    while(*t++)
        tlength++;
    s += slength - tlength;
    printf("%c\n",*t);
    printf("%c\n",*s);
    return ans;
}
void main() {
    char *message = "ratandcat";
    char *message2 = "at";
    int a = strEnd(message,message2);
}
```

But strangely this outputs :

```
%
(and a blank space)
```

But I want my `s` pointer to point to `a`. But it doesn't. Whats going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably meant to move the original pointer here: `s += slength - tlength;` not the one moved to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you have incremented the `s` pointer to the end of the string, and then you add more stuff to it. You could do that loop with something like:

```
while(s[slength])
  ++slength;
```

Another problem is that you are assuming that the s string is longer than the other. What if it's not?  And fix the `;` problem noted by Simon.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semicolon at the end of

```
while(*t++);
```

This means that `tlength` is never incremented, as only the semicolon (empty statement) is executed in the loop.